# How can I do a PHP request like I already have in Python which gives me data in JSON

Tags: php, python, json

I have a Python script which gives me back some data in JSON. It starts a session, posts some auth data and requests data which comes back with JSON. That works fine, but can somebody help me to do this in PHP? I am sure it is possible but I am struggling to construct that.

```
import requests
    with requests.Session() as s:
        start_time = time.time()
        s.post('http://IP:PORT/WHATEVER/AUTH', data={'username':'jdoe','password':'forgotten'})
        req = 'http://IP:PORT/WHATEVER/DATA/BOM%20fe?table=cars,tires,&format=json'
        res = s.get(req)
```

Comment: You struggle with that, but can you post what you have tried so far? You will need to open a session, then use cURL to send and receive data from your endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to look for curl request in php. here is a example

```
function getdata($url){
    if(!function_exists("curl_init"))
        die("cURL extension is not installed");

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $output = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);
    return $output;
}

$output = getdata("https://website.com");
var_dump($output);
```

you can use json decode fuction to covert into matrix and use the variables

```
$arr = json_decode($output,true);
```

you can use something like this for formatting:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
    http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));
```

Comment: This looks very interistign. I installed curl under Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP7. Even after the Apache2.4 restart curl is not enabled. I am trying to solve this issue first and then follow your example.

Comment: @Antwane I got curl working now. I understood your code and the post seems to work. That was part one, because as you can see I am working with a session in my python code. I need to do that with curl too, because otherwise I only get false as response.